# capturing a div with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm stumped.  I have a form that is dynamically populated from the results of a mysql query.  Depending on how many rows are returned, 
the procedure will add a div for each row, and populate each div with a questionaire.  Initially each div is hidden, and for each div
there is a toggle button, and a description of the contents of that record in the mysql table.

Each div is dynamically assigned an id, such as "ACH" plus the index number of the record returned from the mysql query.  In the example
I'm working with now, there are two divs, one is "ACH925" and the other "ACH926", and this is clearly evident in the debugger.

The problem is that the toggle button for the first div toggles both.  No problem with the toggle button for div2; it only toggles
div2.  Also, the toggle button for div1 has a reversible effect on div2.  If both divs are not in the same visibility mode, the div1
toggle button will set div2 to hidden if div1 is set to display, or display when div1 is hidden.

I want each div to be independent and show or hide one or both.

some html code written in a php string, where $value is the index number returned from the query:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows=1;
    for (i=0; i<=rows-1; i++) {
        var table = document.getElementById("ACHTable'.$value.'");
        var row   = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell  = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.width = "12%";
        cell.innerHTML = "<button id=\"shwBtn'.$value.'\" class=\"showBtn\" type=\"button\">Show / Hide</button>";

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.width = "88%";
        cell.style.fontSize="14px";
        cell.innerHTML = "DisputeID: '.$value.';&nbsp;&nbsp;Dispute Date: '.$dd[$ctr].';&nbsp;&nbsp;Merchant: '.$mer[$ctr].'";
        cell.innerHTML+= ";&nbsp&nbsp;Transaction Amount: $'.money_format('%i', ($amt[$ctr]/100)).'";
    }
});
```

and the following code where the toggles are executed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $("#ACH'.$value.'");
    console.log(container.prop("id"));
    $(".showBtn").click(function () {
        container.toggle();
    });
});
```

and finally this from the console, where the divs are visibly evident:

[image]

Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: `cell.innerHTML+='...` Don't do this. Think of `innerHTML` as a "method", not a "property" (though it technically is a property). It takes the HTML you give it, and transforms it into equivalent document objects. You can easily concatenate the multi-line string together and assign innerHTML once at a time.

Comment: thanks Katana314.  good point.  I hadn't thought of that--obviously I was just trying to get a long string pared down to make it readable without scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding this handlers:

```
$(".showBtn").click(function () {
    container.toggle();
});
```

to all existing elements with class declared as `showBtn`. So at end any button will toggle all `container` divs.

You may want to go with this:

```
$("#shwBtn'.$value.'").click(function () {
    container.toggle();
});
```

but thats quite ugly. Better would be to set it properly in buttons' `onclick`.

Easiest for now would be to get use of `$.data()` method, by adding to every button attribute of `data-toggle="#ACH'.$value.'"` and afterward add a click handler to all buttons at once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showBtn").click(function () {
        $($(this).data("toggle")).toggle();
    });
});
```

or something close to this.

Answer (score 0):

you got really close to the answer.

```
$(".showBtn").click(function () {
    container.toggle();
});
```

this will toogle whatever is the value of `container`, you could you `$(this)` instead :

```
$(".showBtn").click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

where this is the object that triggered the click.

---

Edit :
as yergo pointed out, this won't (exactly) fit your problem, but you can easily fix this by changing `.showBtn` to a exclusive class to trigger this, and assign this class to your ACH divs

Answer (score 0):

Scope the selection to the container. This can be done using `.find()` or with a jQuery shortcut where you set the scope in the second argument.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var container = $("#ACH'.$value.'");
 console.log(container.prop("id"));
 $(".showBtn",container).click(function () { //<- button scoped to container
  container.toggle();
 });
});
```